# How to detect scripts failed to load in firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, firebug

I use firefox in my Windows7 PC. There are lot of websites around, which use JavaScript files / libraries with inline script. Normally, a JS load failure may be detected using `<noscript>` tag. But suppose, if a web page (not mine) has 5 .js files from 5 different domains, and one failed to load because of 404 or url blacklist in PC or something else. How can I detect the script which failed to load using firefox? Is this possible using **firebug**?

I don't want to do this programatically. **The page may not be mine**, and of course, I can display a number of error messages if I can edit the page.

Comment: Well, you could set a variable somewhere when a script loaded, then check for that variable.

Comment: Can you explain more about `how` you expect to be able to detect the script that failed?

Comment: the page is not mine. It may be something like Google or StackOverflow

Comment: Read the documentation of the tools you use https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Net_Panel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's possible, you just need to check the `Net` tab, you'll see there loaded files and status for each one.

Comment: @crush: you may be right... but what firebug or firefox has to do here?

Comment: Maybe he thought he could access firebug programmatically, or something? It's unclear what he wants, so your answer seems valid for now.